# List of oppressors of the Jewish people

Tags: history, gentiles, passover-seder-hagada, golus-exile

We say in the *V'hi She'amda* passage of the Pesach Hagaddah that in each and every generation there have been those who rose up against us to destroy us, but Hashem saves us from their designs. Is this literally true?  Has anybody ever complied a list identifying who the Jews' major oppressors were in every generation?  The focus here is on those who rise up against the Jewish people as a whole, not on individual antisemites.  Or are we to understand "in every generation" more informally, like the colloquial "all the time"?

**Moderator's note:** Note that the question does not ask answerers to list oppressors. (That question is not suitable for SE.) It asks whether any commentaries on the hagada (or the like) have already compiled such a list. So concerns that the category "oppressors" is ill-defined or too large are irrelevant: they are good reasons not to compile such a list, but that doesn't mean no one ever did so.

Comment: @SethJ - If a skeptic would ask you whether it's really true that throughout the history of the Jewish people, there was never a generation in which the Jews were left alone without someone trying to destroy them, could you provide any evidence to that effect? I know that I couldn't, at least not without some heavy-duty research. Hence my quest for a list.

Comment: @SethJ Believe it or not, I did find someone who compiled at least a partial list: http://viewpure.com/9AOnACIWAsM  **:)**

Comment: @SethJ, I think the purpose is implicit in the question. To better understand a comment in the Hagada.  In fact, the way the question is currently phrased, it seems to be asking for a list of generations, with one [primary] oppressor (or maybe more) assigned to each. That actually seems tractable and like something that might exist already. If the purpose and desideratum match what I'm suggesting, I recommend sharpening the question a bit along those lines. Still, it looks workable enough to me as-is.

Comment: Dave, I love that song. Saw the video around Purim time; thanks for reminding me! @IsaacMoses, good point! If for no other purpose than writing an awesome Purim Poetry Slam, it's a worthwhile effort. Anyway, I wasn't criticizing the question necessarily, just looking for the motivation.

Comment: @Dave that link doesn;t seem to be working so I'm not sure what it is pointing to. The only song I know which makes any attempt at a list is http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asGS0bE1abQ (tongue firmly in cheek)

Comment: @Danno Try [this link](http://www.gruntig.net/2013/02/PurimPoetrySlamFromAriLesser.html).

Comment: @Dave "If a skeptic would ask you...": Is it such a article of faith that there has to be an oppressor in every singe generation? Perhaps it means: way more often than most people. or even just the colloquial: all the time.

Comment: @DoubleAA, you hit the nail on the head. I'd like to know whether this has ever been shown to be literally true. I think it's generally understood that way.